# iOS: Showing the UIViewControllers when UITabBar and UINavigationBar buttons cliked

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am new to iOS as my project depends on both navigation and the UITabBar controller.I have done the following steps
UITabBar contains 4 buttons and navigation bar contains 2 buttons i.e is common to all the screens 
1)first i have taken the UITabBar controller and added four buttons to it 
2)For each button to the UITabBar i have added the navigation controller 
When i click the tabbar buttons all the views are showing fine and coming to UITabBar bar buttons I am facing the problem as below

suppose I am in UITabBar screen "A" and i clicked the navigation bar button i got the navigation screen ex as "Navscreen"that means now "A" contains 
"Navscreen" when i clicked tabbar button "B" and came back to UITabBar button "A" still its showing the "Navscreen"

To avoid such cases in the "Navscreen" view controller i have added the code as below in the view will appear

```
   -(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController   
   didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
 {
  NSUInteger indexOfTab = [tabBarController.viewControllers 
  indexOfObject:viewController];
  NSLog(@"Tab index = %u (%u)", indexOfTab);

  if (indexOfTab==0)
  {
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"  
 bundle:nil];
    FirstViewController *firstview =
    (FirstViewController *) [storyboard   
   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"home"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:firstview   
   animated:YES];

  }
   else if (indexOfTab==1)
 {
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" 
  bundle:nil];
    secondviewcontroller *secondview =
    (secondviewcontroller *) [storyboard 
     instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Medremainder"];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondview animated:NO];

   }
  if (indexOfTab==2)
    {

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard   
    storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    mymedView *mymed_view =
    (mymedView *) [storyboard 
 instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mymed"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mymed_view   
  animated:NO];
        }

 if  (indexOfTab==3)
{

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard  
   storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    Event_view *event_view =
    (Event_view *) [storyboard 
   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Event_view"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:event_view  
   animated:NO];

    }
}
```

But in this case when click "Navscreen" its working and when I click the UITabBar "B" iam able to get the UITabBar screen.If i click again UITabBar "A" i can see "A" and when i click the UITabBar button "B" app is crashing.AS i am new to ios please help me with the possible solution if i make any thing wrong please suggest with the correct solutions.

Comment: Your description of problem is not very clean, but i suspect you are trying to use TabBar and Navigation controllers in wrong way. Check https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/CombiningViewControllers.html

Comment: yes iam using both navigation and tabbar controllers . i need to get the tabscrees when i clicked the tabbar buttons is clicked .But some of the screens are showing the previouly used navigationbar screens that s my problem

Answer (score 0):

In your `didSelectViewController:`, you seem to be pushing new controllers onto `self.navigationController` multiple times? Each time you select a tab this code will push another controller loaded from storyboard on top of what is already there. This is probably what is messing up your navigation items.

Should you not just be allocating separate navigation controllers once to each tab so this is all automatic?

In storyboard/code allocate separate navigation controllers for each tab. In each navigation controller, create it with a root controller based on what you are loading from storyboard for each tab. You only need to create this once somewhere in your main controller. Then allocate the navigation controllers to separate tabs in storyboard or in code set the array of controllers to be an array of your created navigation controllers.

It should then all be automatic without you needing to implement `didSelectViewController:` at all since each tab will simply cause the appropriate navigation controller to be presented and its associated navigation bar.

Comment: in my did finish launching i have added the code as u said but nothing iam getting .But as u said the same thing is happening in my case

Comment: Can you post the code? If you do all this in storyboard, you should not need any code to set up the tabs and their controllers. Are you using storyboards or doing it by hand? Either way, need to see the code, your storyboard or both.

Comment: iam using story board  i have taken a tabbar controller and added four tabbar buttons and added four navigation controllers to each button and four view s to each navigation controller

Comment: Ok, assuming that your tab bar controller is the initial controller in the storyboard, then you should no code in didFinishLaunching or anywhere else for it to work. It should work just from building and let you change tabs? You will need separate navigationItems for each nav controller. What does it do and not do?

Comment: yes i have done same thing i have given different navigation items in different navigation controllers

Comment: So now when you run it what happens? What works and what does not work?

Comment: Assume i click navigaiton bar button and one view appears that view is in  tab 1 and when i click tab 2 and came back again to tab 1 the same view when i clicked on the navigation bar appears that should not appear  tab 1 view should appear

Comment: When you were in Tab 1, if you pushed a controller on then tab 1 now has that view controller on top of the original. Moving away and coming back to tab 1 will simply show that same navigation stack again. That is what you would expect. If you want to always start at the root when you change tabs then you need to call popToRootController on the navigation controller for the tab when you select it or you will see what was there last time you were on that tab.